# Plotting of Parametric functions using cubic function close to zero generates garbage

Tags: gnuplot

So I'm trying to plot three parametric functions using the gnuplot;
unfortunately, I cannot get around some garbage that is generated in the output plot. I tried to isolate the problem by splitting a function j into j1 and j2, just changing the position of the minus sign. Unexpectedly, the functions j1 and j2 jump strangely when close to the origin. I currently use version 4.6 of gnuplot, any suggestions?

CODE BELOW:

```
set parametric
j1(x) = -((1.0/27.0*(1.+9.*x))/2.0)**(1./3.) #negative portion
j2(x) = (-(1.0/27.0*(1.+9.*x))/2.0)**(1./3.)
k(x) = ((-x/3.0)**(3./2.))**(1./3.)
l(x) = -((-x/3.0)**(3./2.))**(1.0/3.0)

tt(x)  = sqrt(-x/3.)


set trange [-1.0/3.0:0]
set yrange [0:1.0/3.0]
set xrange [-1./6.:1./3]
plot j1(t),tt(t) w l ls 1, j2(t),tt(t) w l ls 1,  k(t),tt(t) w l ls 2,  l(t),tt(t)  w l ls 3
```

Comment: Please provide a complete example of your problem.  I don't see any functions f1 and f2.  Do you mean j1 and j2?  Additionally, should this be done as a parametric plot?  Have you issued the command `set parametric`?

Comment: @Matthew Yes, in fact I made the mistake, it's j1 and j2 and yes, I have issued `set parametric`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem comes from selecting the cube root of a negative number.  Gnuplot can work with complex numbers, and in the complex number system there are three cube roots of any number<sup>**†**</sup>. For a real number, one of these is real and two are complex.  Gnuplot is selecting the first<sup>**‡**</sup> one which is complex for a negative number (for a positive number, the first one is real).

```
print (-8)**(1/3.0) # prints {1.0, 1.73205080756888}
```

The solution is to construct our own cube root function

```
cuberoot(x) = sgn(x)*abs(x)**(1/3.0)
```

This will select take the cube root of the absolute value (always positive) and make the result have the same sign as the original.

We can then use it in our functions

```
j1(x) = -cuberoot((1.0/27.0*(1.+9.*x))/2.0) #negative portion
j2(x) = cuberoot(-(1.0/27.0*(1.+9.*x))/2.0)
```

leaving the rest of the code alone.

### Without custom cuberoot function

[image]

### With custom cuberoot function

[image]

---

<sup>**†**</sup> For the given example of -8, they are 1 + 1.7320508i, -2, and 1 - 1.7320508i.

<sup>**‡**</sup> When ordered in increasing order by complex argument (restricted to the interval [0,2π) ).

Comment: Well, I didn't know gnuplot returned complex numbers when given reals. Question: Are variables in gnuplot always taken as complex?

Comment: @Kbzon I think they are to a certain degree.  Gnuplot will return them when necessary, but you usually won't see them.  This is an edge case.  Without a cube root function and a much smarter algebraic engine, gnuplot doesn't realize that the 1/3 power needs special treatment.  The standard method for finding the 1/3 power in the complex plane will return a complex root first, when we actually want the second one.  The same problem arises with the 1/5, 1/7, 1/9, and so on powers.